# In Star Trek Discovery, is Emperor (Empress?) Georgiou meant to be related to Empress Sato?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-discovery

I wasn't certain if this was the implication, or that it was simply understood to be the case. Certainly the 'mirror universe' might not necessarily be following the same/parallel timeline as in other Star Treks, in this case, Star Trek Enterprise. Just wasn't sure if I missed this connection.

Comment: I seem to recall that all the mirror universes are *supposed* to be the same. That said, there is no reason why Emperors need to be *related* given the erm... *combative* nature of the mirror universe.

Comment: https://screenrant.com/star-trek-discovery-mirror-universe-emperor-georgiou/

Comment: Suspect this might fall under the "future works"  banner.

Comment: ....because she's Asian? Are all people of the same race related? Also - Sato is Japanese, Georgiou's history has her born in America, but the actress is Chinese-Malaysian, so - not even the same. Or are there indications in the episode (asking having not seen it)?

Comment: @NKCampbell, Good point. I'd read some of the MemoryAllpha stuff that elaborated on some of the 'future history' after Sato took over. Hence my question. I realize that not all (or even much) of that is necessarily cannon. The implication was that Sato's lineage extended atleast a couple of generations. So the timeline *might* just work out. Was wondering if I missed it.

Comment: @Paulie_D, If this is "future works", then the answer is 'No', or even perhaps 'Don't know', and the point hasn't been implied yet (so I haven't missed it).

Comment: From what I recall of that ENT episode, the only thing we know for sure is that Sato intended to become empress, not that she actually succeeded. It's possible she tried and failed to steal the empire from Georgiou.

Comment: The Japanese/Chinese split probably doesn't come into it. after ~100 years and possibly 2 to 3 generations depending on practices of abdication in the empire (I for one would much rather retire to a cushy beach than stay THE biggest target in the empire my whole life). then georgiou would only be 1/4 or 1/8th japanese which frankly can often be hardly noticeable. however it isn't unreasonable to assume a unbroken line of succession for a hundred years. and they do have similar eyebrows.

Comment: No canonical data.

Comment: If they ever write a novel in the same vein as *[Age of the Empress](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Age_of_the_Empress)*, I'm sure this will be addressed one way or another.

Comment: They stated her full regal name. No mention of Sato. I would have thought that would be in there somewhere if there was any relation.

Answer (score 8):

**Probably not genetically, but possibly by a chain of adoption**

In S1x12: Vaulting Ambition, Georgiou's list of titles and style is given as:

> All Hail her most Imperial Majesty, Mother of the Fatherland, Overlord
>   of Vulcan, Dominus of Kronos, Regina Andor, All Hail Philippa Georgiou
>   Augustus **Iaponius** Centarius.

The part of particular interest is in the distinctly roman-looking section of her name. Iaponius is latin for Japanese.  [According to Jordan Nardino](https://twitter.com/jnardino/status/955647219402670080?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fio9.gizmodo.com%2Fajax%2Finset%2Fiframe%3Fid%3Dtwitter-955647219402670080%26autosize%3D1), writer for that episode, he considers that Hoshi Sato took the title Iaponius on her ascension to Empress to "honor her homeland".

Nardino goes on to say that given their different ethnic backgrounds, its unlikely they were genetically related. But in the same manner that most Roman emperors adopted someone into their house to name them as heir, he envisages this is how the terran Imperial throne is passed down and Emperor Georgiou is an unbroken chain of succession from Empress Sato 100 years previously.

This is all qualified as "one writer's opinion" and "not canon until it's on screen" by the source, but given the canonical Iaponius among her titles and styles, it seems reasonable to assume that even if Georgiou is not related to Sato, she is at least trying to link herself to the former empress by adopting such a name.

Comment: Interesting observation! I didn't consider the *style* of her regal title (fosusing on the lack of the name Sato instead), but it does bring up a plausible connection.